# how do i make a TextView use up all screen space

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a LinearLayout holding a TextView as follows:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:gravity="left|center"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:paddingBottom="5px"
               android:background="@drawable/drawable_corners_in"
               android:paddingTop="5px" 
               android:paddingLeft="5px">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/i_am_too_small"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:background="#FFFFFF"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:autoLink="web|email|phone|map|all" 
                   android:layout_marginBottom="2px" 
                   android:layout_marginTop="2px">
      </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the screen displays, the TextView is a white bar across the top of the screen.  It is one character tall and stretches across the entire screen.  As text is added, it grows down the screen.

The rest of the screen, below the TextView, is black.

I want the TextView to display and immediate consume the entire screen height so that the entire screen is white.  No black anywhere.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing layout_height in your views from **wrap_content** to **match_parent**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:gravity="left|center"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:paddingBottom="5px"
           android:background="@drawable/drawable_corners_in"
           android:paddingTop="5px" 
           android:paddingLeft="5px">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/i_am_too_small"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:autoLink="web|email|phone|map|all" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="2px" 
               android:layout_marginTop="2px">
  </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Put `fill_parent` to all the layout width and height

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:gravity="left|center"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:paddingBottom="5px"
           android:background="@drawable/drawable_corners_in"
           android:paddingTop="5px" 
           android:paddingLeft="5px">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/i_am_too_small"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:autoLink="web|email|phone|map|all" 
               android:layout_marginBottom="2px" 
               android:layout_marginTop="2px">
  </TextView>
```

Comment: @user1126515 remove all the padding of the LinearLayout

Comment: still the same.  the TextView is only as big as the amount of text currently in it.  does it matter this is being filled up with text by a ArrayAdapter?

Comment: it is a layout of item of a listview??? if yes then you can fill the whole screen

Comment: there is no listview involved.  i have the xml i've posted.  the code that populates it uses an ArrayAdapter and loads it with some Strings that are fields in Objects stored in an ArrayList.

Comment: @user1126515 can you upload the picture of your result

Comment: i am unable to do so.